# How to make navbar appear in page scrollTop, JQuery, & Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, scrolltop

I would like to have a hidden navbar appear once I scroll to a certain part of the page.Im having an issue here with what I'm trying to achieve. I've looked up many examples but I don't know what else to do. Can anyone help me? please and thank you.

**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-danger" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">{{> loginButtons}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height:75px;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 9999;
display: none
}
```

**JQuery**

```
Template.menu.onRendered(function () {
$("#menu").hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 350 ) {

$("#menu").fadeIn();
}
else{
  $("#menu").fadeOut();
}
})
});
```

Comment: **[Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mc35q9y7/1/)**

Comment: That's weird....So what would you think would be the problem why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Its difficult to give proper answer on this as this could not be replicated as is in any platforms here since the actual implementation is different and might include some other codes too..

Comment: it works with me as well. In a meteor demo app. Can you try to print out to console in the `if` to debug `if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 350 ) { console.log('show'); ...` for example

Comment: look this up: http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/